# ASP.NET site on IIS7 getting 401 error. Which is fixed by swapping the NTLM and Negotiate Providers in the applicationHost.config file?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We recently had an issue where a new web appliction was installed on a IIS7 server where users were getting 401 unauthorized errors. Site/server kept asking the user to input their credentials. The site uses windows authentication and users are on the domain.

The solution:
In the applicationHost.config file there are 2 Providers: NTLM and Negotiate. The original setting was clear, Negotiate, then NTML.  We fixed this by swapping the 2 providers (NTLM then Negotiate) and restarting IIS.

I just had a gut feeling but cannot explain why this fixed the issue.

I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE will attempt to leverage Kerberos authentication, and it sounds like IIS is not configured for Kerberos authentication, and IE is not falling back to "plain old" NTLM authentication.

See [windows authentication not working in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337054/windows-authentication-not-working-in-ie7)