# Error 401 and 403 only in Internet Explorer (not in Chrome, Firefox, ..) - IIS configuration?

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-401

I am trying to connect to a site that is running on IIS on my local machine.

When I am using Anonymous Authentication, it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE I get HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized.

The error details are:
Module: ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler: System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
Error Code: 0x00000000
Requested URL: http://localhost:80/
Logon Method: Anonymous
Logon User: Anonymous

When using Windows Authentication, it also works in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE I get HTTP Error 403.0 - Forbidden.

The only difference in error details is the Logon User (which is my login to intranet network) and Logon Method (which is "Negotiate" or "NTLM", depending on which I choose as provider for Windows authentication - according to [windows authentication not working in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337054/windows-authentication-not-working-in-ie7/10651095#10651095) and [401 - Unauthorized in IE7 only with windows authentication.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188994/401-unauthorized-in-ie7-only-with-windows-authentication))

- I can access the site running on another machine in IE
- On different machine the site in its localhost can be accessed in IE
- The site running on my computer can be accessed from other computers in Chrome or Firefox, but not in IE (gives 401 or 403)
- I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, IE 11

It seems that the problem is somewhere in the IIS configuration or maybe in some incompatibility between IE and IIS. I am not able to locate the difference between the configuration on my computer and the others.

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE:
It works in compatibility mode with IE 10 and 9.
(I was looking at IIS configuration so much that trying compatibility mode didn't cross my mind at all.) Still, my colleague was somehow using the same version without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there was someone interested in a solution that worked for me:

The problem was that up to version 10, Internet Explorer was using "MSIE" in its user agent string. We were using the user agent to recognize it as a known browser, so changing this logic fixed my issue.